# How to put ID in POST form (YII2)

Tags: php, yii2

I am newbee in Yii2 and now I try to build rent-a-car system especially for practise. Now I try to make an order-form. How could I put Car's ID in POST form? My code with form and Car's description below.
[image]

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-3">
        <?php
        if(Yii::$app->session->hasFlash('success')){
            echo Yii::$app->session->getFlash('success');
        }
        if(Yii::$app->session->hasFlash('error')){
            echo Yii::$app->session->getFlash('error');
        }
        $form = ActiveForm::begin([
            'id' =>'order-form',
            'action' => ['site/contract'],
            'options' => ['class' => 'form-horizontal']
        ]) ?>
        <?= $form->field($model, 'first_date') ?>
        <?= $form->field($model, 'second_date') ?>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-lg-offset-1 col-lg-11">
                <?= Html::submitButton('Order', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php ActiveForm::end() ?>

    </div>
    <!-- /.col-lg-3 -->
    <div class="col-lg-9">
        <div class="card mt-4">
            <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="<? echo $car->getImage()?>" alt="">
            <div class="card-body">
                <h3 class="card-title"><? echo $car->mark?> <? echo $car->model?></h3>
                <h4 style="color: red">$<? echo $car->price?> per day</h4>
                <p class="card-text"><? echo $car->description?></p>
                <span class="text-warning">&#9733; &#9733; &#9733; &#9733; &#9734;</span>
                4.0 stars
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /.card -->

    </div>
</div>
```

It's mine Controller but now it's pure:

```
public function actionContract() {
    $model = new OrderForm();

    if($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->validate()){
        Yii::$app->session->setFlash('success','Заявка отправлена');
    }
    else {
        Yii::$app->session->setFlash('error','Проверьте данные');
    }
    return $this->redirect(['site/view']);
}
```

Comment: You probably want to create dropdown list where you can select which car you want to rent, but you question is not clear so it's hard to tell what are you trying to achieve.

Comment: Oh no) I put screenshot to the question. I have a list with different cars (from DB). When you choose a car you click to button and system redirects you to car-details page (in the scrsh). And here user could make an order when chose dates and click button. But for creating order object I have to take Car's ID

Comment: add relevant controller and form code.

Comment: @InsaneSkull I've added Controller but now I think it isn't important I just want to catch $car->id and put it in ActiveForm

Comment: So on car-detail page add hidden field to form with car id

Comment: Where is `$car` you are referring in view? Either pass `$car->id` as **hidden input**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add hidden input field as below to your form:

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'id')->hiddenInput(['value'=> $value])->label(false); ?>

or

<?= Html::hiddenInput('id', $value); ?>
```

and when you process the form, just retrieve the id like normal field, here `$value` is the id you want to pass